# How can I keep the grid of 4 x 2 with different size of images with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid of 4 x 2 with product images and some text overlaying the image. The problem is that the images are going to be all different aspect ratios.

What tends to happen is that if one image is significantly higher than the rest, it will push the other images out of alignment. I am trying to find a way to keep all the boxes the same height, with the text in the same position on each image, with just the picture scaling itself down to fit.

This is also responsive, so please enlarge the preview window on jsfiddle to see the issue I am having.

In this example, I have used the correct image dimensions.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/w533z8Lg/3/

EDIT: Removing the `max-height:292px` and just having `height:292px` for the images works in terms of the layout is correct, but the smaller images are stretched to that height, and resizing doesn't keep the aspect ratio.

EDIT 2: I found this JSFiddle which was a solution to someone else with the same issue, I will try to understand it. http://jsfiddle.net/ETkkR/7/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row featured_products list-group">
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x272/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 1</span></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x270/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 2</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x272/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 3</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x235/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 4</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x274/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 5</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x160/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 6</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x272/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item 7</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 featured_product">
        <div class="padding">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="innerpadding product-thumbnail"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/226x292/8f8f8f/575757.jpg" /><span class="featured_product_title"><span>Item  8</span></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.featured_product {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.featured_products div.padding {
    padding:5px 10px;
}
.featured_products div.padding div.border {
    border:1px solid #EAEAEA;
}
.featured_products div.padding div.border div.innerpadding {
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
.featured_products div.padding div.border div.innerpadding img {
    max-height:292px;
    display:inline-block;
}
span.featured_product_title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:6px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:RGBa(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    vertical-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    height:50px;
    color:#46436f;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: It helps some what, but doesn't solve the issue. Feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make all the images as the same size without cutting off.

What you can do is adding the necessary clear fix on the items, for every size you're targeting. That will make the them stay in the correct grid. Bootstrap targets those three breakpoints.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/w533z8Lg/5/

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .featured_products .item:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .featured_products .item:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: none;
    }
    .featured_products .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
      clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .featured_products .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
      clear: none;
    }
    .featured_products .item:nth-child(4n+1) {
      clear: both;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. I haven't marked it as the answer to the question, as it doesn't solve the issue I were having. It does however help with the formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before with projects I was working on. What I ended up doing was using the Masonry library in conjunction with Bootstrap. http://masonry.desandro.com/. My conditions were the aspect ratio had to remain, they had to have the same width, and the I knew the heights would be unpredictable.

Granted, it doesn't keep all things in a straight horizontal line, but it sure eliminates the huge empty white spaces that you're talking about.

Comment: I can see how that works, good for article walls, but in this case I would need to have everything in line. Thanks

Comment: Just seen your edit. I did just set my heights all to 292px instead of max-height, and this actually works in terms of the layout is correct, but the pictures get squashed.