# Issue with keeping images ratios, and displaying in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap

I have a row of 4 images. Each image is a different size and aspect ratio. some tall and thin, some short and wide.

I am trying to get them to display within four boxes, centered both vertically and horizontally, without overflowing or being squashed. How can I do this?

Currently I have this:
[image: Currently]

I would like to get it to display like this:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row list-group">
    <div class="item col-xs-3 featured_product">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x900/a3a3a3/3b3b3b.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-3 featured_product">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/700x300/a3a3a3/3b3b3b.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-3 featured_product">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x100/a3a3a3/3b3b3b.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-3 featured_product">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/a3a3a3/3b3b3b.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imagecontainer {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
.imagecontainer img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height:290px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0kt00prh/

Comment: What browser compatibility do you need? is flexbox an option?

Comment: As much as possible really. I've looked at flexbox for this before but it seems too overkill for doing something as simple as this should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this, it's using css `transform` works on IE9 and up. and using transparent borders for the spacing, there might be other ways for doing it but it seems working good.

http://jsfiddle.net/0kt00prh/1/

```
.imagecontainer {
    position: relative;
}
.imagecontainer img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I have put off doing this for so long. I even have another post here on the same thing. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014218/how-can-i-keep-the-grid-of-4-x-2-with-different-size-of-images-with-bootstrap). Nothing went right. But you've hit the nail on the head with this one and it's perfect! Many thanks!

Comment: I've marked the other as the answer too. You've made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a solution:

```
.imagecontainer {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.imagecontainer img {
    width:100%;
      position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

It will only work for more modern browsers. IE9+

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0kt00prh/2/)